# Why does align-items not center the div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I tried to center the text under the header in the vertically in the body. What I learned, was to use `align-items`, since I already changed the div's `display` to `flex`. What could be the problem here?

I'm new to css and html so please be patient with me:

```css
/*
Color-palette:
    #b6b6b6     
    #4c4c4c
    #343434
    #0c0c0c
    #c8984c
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 62, 5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.t {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

header {
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 50px 50px 10px;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ul-navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.ul-navigation li a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

.container button {
  background: #343434;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.container button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(211, 205, 198, 0.3);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.contact-button a {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.container-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-body h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #c8984c;
}

.container-body p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="container">

    <h1 class="logo">SMAR<span class="t">T</span>IK</h1>

    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="ul-navigation">
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="contact-button"><a href="#">Contact</a></button>
  </header>

  <div class="container-body">
    <h1>Ut neque qui ut<br />deleniti et.</h1>
    <p> Molestiae a nobis molestiae mollitia eos dolor qui.<br /> Delectus voluptate vel alias iusto autem quos ipsam eligendi. </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: to center an element you need a specific height not a calculated height. The height needs to taller then the content. Also `align-items` does not have the `baseline` value which is for the  `vertcial-align` property

Answer (score 0):

Which elements do you want to center using flexbox?

I'm assuming you want to center the `.container-body`
It's not centering because both elements on the `.container-body`(h1 and p) together are occupying 100% of the width. So, to fix it you should specify a width into the `h1` and `p`. Keep in mind that the sum of both width should be less than the width of the `.container-body`

I did the following:

```
.container-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-body p{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    width: 40%  /* I set width to 40%, but can be a width that fits your needs*/
}
```

If you want to display the elements inside the `.container-body` as a column, you can add `flex-direction: column;` to the `.container-body`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `flex-direction: column;` to `.container-body`:

```
.container-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* <---- add this line */
    align-items: center;
}
```